# Meteor application install on iphone ipad with custom server

Tags: ios, iphone, meteor

Hi the situation is like this. I have an application build on Meteor And now I would like to test it on my phone. So I did the following steps
from this tutorial https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Meteor-Cordova-integration

so I did meteor run ios --mobile-server http://192.168.1.2:3000

the command above started the xCode, then I did select my iPhone and I did click [Run], the xCode said that the app has been built. All this is ok, but it's not showing on my phone. If someone can help me with this would be great thank you in advance.